# Repeat a javascript replace until no change is made?

Tags: javascript

I have a short but complex regular expression to trim spaces regardless of html tags present in the string.

```js
var text = "<span><span>ex ample </span> </span>";
// trim from start; not relevant in this example
text = text.replace(/^((<[^>]*>)*)\s+/g, "$1");
// trim from end
text = text.replace(/\s+((<[^>]*>)*)$/g, "$1");
console.log(text);
```

`<span><span>ex ample </span> </span>` - example input
`<span><span>ex ample</span></span>` - expected output
`<span><span>ex ample </span></span>` - observed output

How do I achieve my expected output?
I've tried adding the `/g` flag because it should supposedly match more than once and that should fix it (running the replace twice does work for the example) but it doesn't seem to repeat anything at all.
Alternative ways to trim strings regardless of tags are also appreciated because that is my primary objective. The secondary objective is learning why this didn't work.

Comment: The `g` flag makes it keep looking for further matches _after_ the found first match, but that is not necessarily the same as _executing_ the replace twice.

Comment: I have ultimately decided that the original flawed solution worked for my case. It's an improbable situation with an easy fix - just repeat the action (saving) that runs this code. Thanks to @04FS I think I now understand why it was flawed. All matches happen before any replacements. Additionally, it seems matches cannot be present inside of other matches.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some meaning to your tags, some need their spaces, some don't.

Try this:

```
text.replace(/\s*(<\/?(span|div)>)\s*/g, "$1")
    .trim()
    .replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

It:

- replaces spaces around tags "surrounding" content
- trims spaces around global string
- removes redundant spaces

The list of "surrounding" tags can be changed to include things like `tr`...

Steps 2 and 3 might come first to speed things up.

Tried it with:

```
var text = "<div> <i>ano</i>   <b>ther</b>  <span> <b>my</b>   <i>ex</i> <u> ample </u> </span> </div>";
```

#### First answer, prior to comments.

The idea is to remove all spaces between:

- a non-space character and an opening tag
- a closing tag and a non-space character

```
text.replace(/([^\s])\s*(<)/g, "$1$2")
    .replace(/([>])\s*([^\s])/g, "$1$2")
    .trim();
```

Comment: I really like where this is going. The only thing that it doesn't do is trim spaces before the first tag and after the last tag... which is something the regular `.trim()` can do, so the combination works perfectly!

Comment: Nevermind, it still likes to delete spaces it shouldn't delete in very specific cases. Here is one: `<span> ex <i>ample</i> <u>case</u> </span>`. It is not supposed to delete the space between `ample` and `case`.

Comment: Edited the answer. This was not in your exemple ;)

Comment: (Sorry for jumping my comment right before yours, it just happened)
I want to point out that none of my objectives is just the example. I want to a) trim spaces from the _start and end_ of a string containing tags b) figure out why my code in the question didn't work.

Comment: Your problem is not that trivial. In this string: `"<span><span> <i>ex</i> <u>ample </u> </span> </span>";` how can you figure if you remove the space between `<span>` and `<i>` but not between `</i>` and `<u>`?

Comment: There exists _visible_ text both before and after the closing `</i>` tag, therefore the space next to it is part of the _visible_ text and not just padding on the sides. I want to remove padding on the sides because when you render this string as html, you see ` ex ample  ` with annoying spaces at start and end. I've made my own answer that does everything I need and can be referred to. But it has a problem (pointed out in said answer). It also doesn't answer why the original didn't work. If something is still not clear about the problem, please comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

**Preamble: don't just copy this, read to the end.**
Thinking from the other way around - by replacing until *no match* is found instead of until *no change* is made, this seems to work very simply.

```js
var text = "<span><span>ex ample </span> </span>";
var trim_start = /^((<[^>]*>)*)\s+/;
while(text.match(trim_start)) {
  text = text.replace(trim_start, "$1");
}
var trim_end = /\s+((<[^>]*>)*)$/;
while (text.match(trim_end)) {
  text = text.replace(trim_end, "$1");
}
console.log(text);
```

The output is as expected - the only space is between `ex ample`

But this has a *big* problem if the replace might not change anything. Simply changing `\s+` to `\s*` makes it turn into an infinite cycle. So, all in all, it works for my case but is not robust and to use it, you must be completely sure every single replace will change something when the regex matches.

Comment: One possible optimization to this: only call `match()` if the string was not changed.